# Routing and Authorization in Angular 7

Tags: angular, routes, jwt

I try to implement standard JWT authorization with routing in Angular 7. The part of my app-routing.module.ts:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
  {
    path: '401',
    component: UnauthorizeComponent
  }
```

I also have auth.service.ts:

```
const helper = new JwtHelperService();
const myRawToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
const isExpired = helper.isTokenExpired(myRawToken);

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

...

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return !isExpired;
```

Also - auth-guard.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService  implements CanActivate {

...

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['401']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

And in Header component I have dropdown-list with "login" item and my code there is:

```
sendLogin() {

    const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('username', this.loginForm.value.login)
      .set('password', this.loginForm.value.password);

    this.authService.login(body.toString())
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          return ......;
        }))
      .pipe(
        tap(resp => {
          localStorage.setItem('token', resp.headers.get('Authorization'));
          this.router.navigate(['']);
        }))
      .subscribe();
  }
```

So, it works fine, but *this.router.navigate([''])* in my header component doesn't work. Instead of '' url browser opens *this.router.navigate(['401']);* because helper.isTokenExpired(myRawToken) can't refresh token. But if I press F5 (refresh) in browser and go to localhost:4200/ - my page opens.

What am I doing wrong?

How to refresh token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your token is in localStorage, any service takes it from there at initialization. Thus, during authorization, you put a token in localStorage, but the authorization service that the guard refers to keeps a variable in its variable that does not yet have a token from localStorage. Therefore, with F5, you initiate a service and it already sees it. It is necessary to expand the authorization service so that as soon as the answer comes, the data in the token variable

Comment: Thanks! It works for me! I wrote a new method in auth service refreshyoken():  myRawToken = localStorage.getItem('token');  isExpired = helper.isTokenExpired(myRawToken); And after that it works good!